# "Generic" @XmlRootElement?

Tags: jaxb

I'm working against a very large API, most of whose return values look like:

```
<{APIMethodName}Resp>
  <ResponseCode></ResponseCode>
  <ResponseMessage></ResponseMessage>
</{APIMethodName}Resp>
```

Is there any sort of JAXB fu that will let me do this with just one class? I'm ok if JAXB ignores the root, just throws it away.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the unmarshal method that take a class parameter.  This causes the JAXB implementation to ignore the root element.

Comment: Ah, so it would unmarshal into the the class named by the parameter assuming the attributes in the named class lineup with the xml?

Comment: Yes, that'll do just fine in lieu of 30 or so classes that only differ by their root. Thanks!